# Instance php7.2 php-xml, php-soap on aws ec2 instance running under centos

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, moodle, totara

I really really need help getting moodle up and running on one of my aws ec2 instance, I am facing difficulty installing and enabling php-xml extension on centos. I tried all the solutions available online, but none worked for me.

Here is what i tried so far:

On a new aws ec2 instance, done following ;

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 install php-xml
```

//this installs the extension but for some reason the extension is not loading. I can see /etc/php.d/20-dom.ini, but that don't seems to load here

http://ec2-52-66-197-132.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/info.php
http://ec2-52-66-197-132.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test.php

I took this reference from this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122104/how-to-install-php-xml-in-centos)

Also i followed the solution proposed here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-install-php-xml-php-mbstring-etc-in-php-7-0

```
curl 'https://setup.ius.io/' -o setup-ius.sh
sudo bash setup-ius.sh
```

I get the message "not an EL distro"

Will really appreciate any quick help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you restart webserver? `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`

Comment: Yes Andrea, i restarted server many times using sudo service httpd restart

Comment: please post output of `sudo yum install php7.2-xml`

Comment: Here: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-19 ~]$ sudo yum install php7.2-xml
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                               | 2.4 kB     00:00
No package php7.2-xml available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Please output of `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 install php-xml`?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ovj80c

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ovj8lf

Comment: Have you try `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Comment: This solved my problem, can you elaborate on how does this solution work?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

Comment: Solved my prob too. Thanks.

Comment: @Gonzalingui The FPM process does not read the config files or load its plugins until it is restarted, and it's a separate process from Apache/httpd.